# System mail not being forwarded via /etc/aliases

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

I have a server set up and I'd like to have any mail sent to the root system mailbox auto-forwarded to my email address.

Following instructions found via google, I've added this line to /etc/aliases:

root:

I've also added a text file at /root/.forward with my email address as the contents.

I've run the following commands:

sudo newaliases
sudo service postfix restart

Postfix restarted without error.

When I send the root user a system mail using the following command:

echo "testing" | mail -s "Test subject" root

No mail comes into the root user's system account (whereas before setting up the alias, it would show new messages when I logged in as root and typed the 'mail' command).

So that makes me think the alias is working.

But it's been over an hour since the first test messages were sent and I haven't received anything yet (not even in my spam folder).

Have I missed an important step?

Server is ubuntu 18.04.6

Comment: I think you've missed an important step of checking the Postfix log files for any error messages?

Comment: The config line states `root:`, I think you are missing something here. Do you have, in the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file, a line with `alias_maps = lmdb:/etc/aliases`? Have you rebuilt the aliases db with `postalias /etc/aliases`?. You are also better to create a `/etc/aliases.local` and use that for any local changes, as the system one could get wiped. If you do, remember to update `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.